# Set default action in a form

Tags: javascript, html

I develop a website with java/jsp have a form with 2 submit button :

```
<form>
    <button name="view_step1" type="submit">
        Previous
    </button>

    <button name="action_step2" type="submit">
        Next
    </button>                           
</form>
```

How can to do for execute the second button when the user click on "enter"?

Comment: write a javascript function and call that when user click "enter"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
document.getElementById("id-of-form-or-somthing-else")
.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById("id-of-your-second-button").click();
}
});
```

Comment: I thinked their is a better way but this one will be fine.Thx.